# Which loop to use, R language?

Tags: r

We have to create function(K) that returns vector which has all items smaller than or equal to K from fibonacci sequence. We can assume K is fibonacci item. For example if K is 3 the function would return vector (1,1,2,3).

Comment: If you're learning to use R (which it sounds like your are) you should avoid using loops if you can. One of the key features of R is it's ability to apply functions to vectors. Look into using the `apply` series of functions. You won't learn anything if you just port a python script to R.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] give a [mcve]!

Answer (score 0):

In general, a `for` loop is used when you know how many iterations you need to do, and a `while` loop is used when you want to keep going until a condition is met.

For this case, it sounds like you get an input `K` and you want to keep going until you find a Fibonacci term `> K`, so use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
     ans <- function(n) {
     x <- c(1,1)
     while (length(x) <= n) {
     position <- length(x)
     new <- x[position] + x[position-1]
     x <- c(x,new)
     }
     return(x[x<=n])
     }
```

`

Tried many different loops, and this is closest I get. It works with every other number but ans(3) gives 1,1,2 even though it should give 1,1,2,3. Couldn't see what is wrong with this.